# Get mypy to recognise that object has attribute

Tags: python, mypy

For example:

```py
from typing import Union, List, TypeVar

foo: object

if hasattr(foo, 'bar'):
    print(foo.bar)
```

returns

```
main.py:6: error: "object" has no attribute "bar"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, we know that `foo` has attribute `bar`, because we just asserted it - is there any way to tell mypy this?

Comment: [Relevant mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1424)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a `Protocol` instead of `hasattr`:

```
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable


@runtime_checkable
class HasBar(Protocol):
    bar: int


foo: object

if isinstance(foo, HasBar):
    print(foo.bar)
```